# Setting up cookie options

Tags: c#, .net-core, setcookie

Creating simple method and seems like the 'cookieOptions' function are not working and Im getting stack on its reference prerequisites.

May I know what reference or module needs to be import to enable the capability of this

Here is the sample method:

```
public void SetCookie(string key, string value, int? expireTime)
{
    CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions(); /// => Missing reference here      
}
```

And here is the returning error:

```
'CookieOptions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Any suggestions/comments TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using net core (nothing like this in .net framework)

**Namespace**:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

**Assembly**:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookieoptions?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Answer (score 1):

Assembly name Microsoft.AspNet.Http.CookieOptions for .net framework
If you code .net core you can use this one Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http